# Appium go to URL on iOS (real device) will encounter "('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))"

Tags: python, ios, webdriver, appium

My Python Appium client version is 0.48

I using Appium to go to URL on iOS real device:

```
iOS_driver.get("http://link.xxx/")
```

will encounter error:

```
raise BadStatusLine(line)
ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

is any other way to open url or deep link on iOS real device?

Answer (score 0):

It works this way:

`driver.get("theapp://path/);`, where path is actual link

Real example:
driver.get("theapp://login/user1/test123456");

You can check an article about it [here](https://appiumpro.com/editions/7)